# Ansible filter AWS AMI ID with dates

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

```
 - name: gather information about all AMIs with tag key Name and value webapp
  amazon.aws.ec2_ami_info:
    filters:
       "tag:Version": "*"
  register: ec2ami_result 

- debug:
    msg: "{{ ec2ami_result  }}"
 - set_fact:
    AMI_newid: "{{ ec2ami_result | json_query ('images[?(@.creation_date=='2020-06-30T05:17:36.000Z')].image_id') }}"
```

I am getting ec2ami json data with bunch of images, now i want to filter them using creation_date and then get its image_id.

I get error

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while
> templating string: expected token ',', got 'integer'. String: {{
> ec2ami_result | json_query
> ('images[?(@.creation_date=='2020-06-30T05:17:36.000Z')].image_id')
> }}"}

Is there is something i need to fix, also is there is way i can only get image_ids before date specified so lets say 2020-05-20, all image id created before this date ?

fix:
just use
amazon.aws.ec2_ami_info:
filters:
creation-date: "2020-*"

This way you can get any ami belonging to that year.

Comment: Hi Hardik Pargi welcome to SO. (a) you cannot have single quotes within single quoted strings without escaping them (b) JMESPath uses [the backtick ` for string literals](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#literal-expressions) within an expression like that (c) you're currently filtering them client-side, but [`ec2 describe-images` supports a `creation-date` filter server-side](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html#options). Good luck

Comment: Awesome, it worked, also now i understand just use creation-date filter in ec2 describe-images. I think this worked as awell, i can get now images from any year. Super helpful. Thanks daniel.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was something simple. Please [answer and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your own solution so that others can benefit from your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter ami for year just use Filters

amazon.aws.ec2_ami_info: filters: creation-date: "2020-*"

This will return only value from creation-date